# Why does my function know a value of an attribute without a assignment rule?

Tags: python, variables, attributes, variable-assignment, static-methods

I've started learning Python recently and got this code here:

```
import math

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius ** 2

    @staticmethod
    def convert_area_in_radius(area):
        return math.sqrt(area/math.pi)


c2 = Circle(Circle.convert_area_in_radius(80))

print(c2.radius)
```

If I run my console the return is 5.04..

That makes sense for me because of calling the def `convert_area_in_radius`.
But where does Python know it is assigned to the attribute `radius` of the `init` method? I mean I am calling

`print(c2.radius)`

there is know reference to this attribute `radius`

I expected to get the same return but not with calling `print(c2.radius)`

Comment: `c2 = Circle("bla bla"); print(c2.radius)` .....

Comment: You have created an instance of the class, who's constructor assigns `radius`. What is unclear here?

Comment: The crucial line here is `c2 = Circle(...)`: The call `Circle(...)` implicitly calls the `__init__()` method on the newly created `Circle` instance (called `c2` afterward). In this call of `__init__()`, the `self` argument implicitly receives the newly created instance, while the `radius` argument receives the value that results from calling `convert_area_in_radius()` (it acts as a positional argument here). After that, `self.radius = radius` sets the `radius` field on the new instance. If all of this is confusing, make yourself familiar with working with classes in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting expressions. Here a "denested" version

```
# using a "function" associated to the class 
r = Circle.convert_area_in_radius(80)

# creating the instance
c2 = Circle(r)

# access to the attribute of the instance
print(c2.radius)
#5.046265044040321

# call the method of the instance
print(c2.area())
#80.00000000000001 # almost the original (due to pi, or in general to float-limitations)
```

A `convert_area_in_radius` is a **static method** has no explicit information about the neither of instance nor the class it belongs to.

Instead `area` is method that is **bound** the the instance and that's why you need to pass a `self` parameter.